# Signal Superposition and divider?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, voltage-detector

I am all out of MCU pins and would like to add a voltage sense function. This will only be necessary when the device first starts up. I have a somewhat sensitive signal already connected to my ADC, but I would like to add my voltage sense signal to this original signal as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFzS47.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the device first starts up, there will be negligible potential on the signal line. This means I should measure 3 volts, scaling it up in software by 50/3 to get my supply voltage reading. When the signal circuitry powers up, will the effect of the supply sense divider be 100 times smaller than that of the signal because of the resistance ratios? Is such an approach unlikely to succeed  for other reasons I have overlooked?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the signal is high-impedance before I fire up that part of the circuit.

Comment: How much accuracy do you require on these two readings?

Comment: @user2943160 3% should suffice

Answer (score 0):

All the resistors act all the time.

If your signal processing really presents and open circuit (I.e. a transistor or relay ensures that), then you 50V value is being sensed with a 3k in the lower leg; the senses value will be small and hard to sense accurately.

If the signal processor pulls to a specific voltage, the analysis is a bit more complicated, but the small value of the 3k will likely still dominate.

Answer (score 0):

300k is in parallel with 3k, that is as good as keeping a single 3k. So when you apply 50V, what you get is a few millivolts. I would use a multiplexer if there are not enough pins. But if you don't want to go there, I can think of some solutions as given below. But these would require some compromises in the implementation. You might have to recalculate the circuit values for turn on/off conditions.
[image]

The effect of 50V will appear only until capacitors charge up in these circuits. In the circuit on the left the anode of D2 will have some voltage even after the capacitor C2 is fully charged, however, I assume the signal path output at D3 will dominate this value.

In the circuit on the right, while the 50V is turned off, there will be a small negative voltage at the ADC pin (~0.1-0.4V for a Schottky diode). It should be within the adc limits, but you should check the datasheet.

Comment: I was very tired last night indeed! These options could work for my solution but I wounder if I could add the resistor divider to a digital line that could also serve as an input to the ADC...